# Shiny apps cannot select Input on levels with ggplots

Tags: r, ggplot2, levels, shiny

I have a hard time subsetting shiny plots (ggplots) on levels and didn't find any example to help...
I would like to be able to choose x and y levels with checkboxes and plot on ly selected levels.

Here a subset of my data:

```
Jahr <- c(2014,2015,2020)
RW<- c(0,45,80)
Aus<- c(0,10,80)
Revit<- c(0,10,50)
Point_size<-c(0,30,0)
df3 <- data.frame(Jahr,RW,Aus,Revit,Point_size)
df3_melt <- melt(df3 , id=c("Jahr","Point_size"))
```

my ui:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
headerPanel('Gewaesser'),
sidebarPanel(
checkboxGroupInput("jahr", "Jahr", choices = levels(df3_melt$Jahr)),
checkboxGroupInput("thema", "Thema", choices = levels(df3_melt$variable)),
mainPanel(
  plotOutput('plot1')
)
))
```

and server:

```
server <- function(input, output) {

 #   selectedData <- reactive({
 #     all[,levels(df3_melt$variable]
 #   })
output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
ggplot(df3_melt, aes(x=input$jahr,y=value)) +
  geom_line(aes(group=input$thema,         color=input$thema),size=0.5,linetype="dashed")+ 
  geom_segment(aes(x = 2014, y = 0, xend = 2015, yend = 45),colour="red",size=0.4)+ #ist
  geom_segment(aes(x = 2014, y = 0.5, xend = 2015, yend = 10.5),colour="green",size=0.4)+ #ist
  geom_segment(aes(x = 2014, y = 0, xend = 2015, yend = 9.8),colour="blue",size=0.4)+ #ist
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0,101),xlim=c(2014,2020.5))+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=c(2014,2015, 2016, 2017,2018,2019,2020), labels=c("Baseline","GJ 2015","GJ 2016","GJ 2017","GJ 2018","GJ 2019","Sollwert 2020"),minor_breaks=seq(2015, 2019, by=2))+
  geom_segment(aes(x = 2020, y = 0, xend = 2020, yend = 100,alpha=0.5),colour="chartreuse3",size=4)+ #Zielwert
  geom_segment(aes(x = 2015, y = 0, xend = 2015, yend = 100),colour="black",size=0.5)+
  theme(plot.background = element_blank(),
        axis.title.y = element_blank(),
        axis.title.x = element_blank(),
        panel.border = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_rect(color="white",fill="white"),
        axis.text.x = element_text(size=6, angle=45, hjust=1, color="black"),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size=6,  hjust=1, color="black"),
        legend.title = element_blank(),
        #legend.key.size=unit(1),
        legend.key = element_rect(colour = 'white', fill = 'white', size = 0.5)
  )+
  guides(fill = guide_legend(label.position = "bottom"))
 })

 }
```

Help would be greatly appreciated, shiny looks amazing, but tricky with levels...
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Thanks a lot for your help I just found the solution, the only problem remaining ist, that it doesn't plot 2 levels at the same time....

```
 ui<-shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
headerPanel('Gewässer'),
sidebarPanel(
checkboxGroupInput("var", "Indikatoren auswählen zu A1", choice = levels(df3_melt$variable))
),
 mainPanel(
 plotOutput("plot2")
)
))


server<-shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
output$plot2 <- renderPlot({
par(mar = c(5.1, 4.1, 0, 1))
ggplot(df3_melt[df3_melt$variable == input$var, ],  aes_string(x="Jahr",y="value")) +
  geom_line(aes_string(group="variable", color="variable"),size=0.5,linetype="dashed")
})

 })
  shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0):

use `aes_string(x = input$jahr, y = "value")` instead of `aes(x=input$jahr,y=value)`

Comment: Thanks but this didn't solve the problem.... Still have some dimension issues... Also when using reactive(...)

Comment: Note that you will to put all `input` into an `aes_string()` instead of `aes()`. Furthermore, it would be useful if you create a *minimal* example: remove everything which isn't related to your problem from the code. a) that easier to spot the problem b) people don't like to digest large chunks of code unrelated to the problem.